# Obteniendo errores al validar la instalación de xdebug en PHPStorm IDE, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlos?

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

**Hola, necesito configurar e instalar xdebug para mi php usando xamp, seguí los tutoriales en youtube.
AHORA**

1. xdebug están instalados correctamente
2. PERO cuando trato de validar la instalación de xdebug en phpstorm IDE tengo los siguientes errores en las fotos, pero traté de arreglarlo con la ayuda de chatgpt pero no tuve éxito.

[image: img_aquí_de_problemas]

**¿Lo que esperaba?**

Necesito ayuda para resolver o corregir todos los problemas marcados con triángulos de advertencia amarillos y los demás problemas con círculos azules.

**Aquí los enlaces de los tutoriales que usé.**

1. instalando xdebug [video1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3y4oH9LLxc&t=0s&ab_channel=Gragot)
2. configurando xdebug [video2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wZc6kf8pv4&ab_channel=Gragot)

saludos por ayuda.

**Nota:** probé con la **validación del segundo método**, antes en el artículo principal aquí traté de validar con

> SERVIDOR WEB LOCAL O CARPETA COMPARTIDA

método y segunda opción que probé usando

> copiar/pegar phpinfo

en este segundo método tengo menos errores, solo 3 errores y se ve muy bien

Necesito ayuda para resolver o solucionar todos los problemas marcados con triángulos de advertencia amarillos y los otros problemas del círculo azul.

**configuración xdebug aquí**

[image: xdebug:config aquí]

**archivo php_info aquí detalles**

> Solo abra el enlace y haga clic para acercar para ver todo el archivo
> capturado por completo, **puede usar `CTRL + F` para encontrar texto
> en la imagen si puede**

[phpinfo](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/40036446?key=054ce840d103e6c16c7686f0f5c5eccc)

**Estas son las instrucciones de chatgpt que seguí para seguir tu sugerencia.**

[chatgpt para seguir tu sugerencia aquí](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/40036633?key=d482326518509a88423666792ea3af31)

> Solo abra el enlace y haga clic para acercar para ver todo el archivo
> capturado por completo, **puede usar `CTRL + F` para encontrar texto
> en la imagen si puede**

**Aquí está mi archivo php.ini**

[php.ini](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/40036793?key=b19f59aafea0dc3bc8cd877ed4dc8cd1)

> Solo abra el enlace y haga clic para acercar para ver todo el archivo
> capturado por completo, **puede usar `CTRL + F` para encontrar texto
> en la imagen si puede**

Comment: Hola. Centra tu pregunta en el problema, por ejemplo, no vamos a ver los vídeos que viste para realizar tu trabajo. Aquí interesa el problema y resolverlo. Es más útil si nos dices qué has hecho para resolver los errores. Por ejemplo, te dice que el puerto `9003` está ocupado. ¿Liberaste ese puerto o intentaste hacer que el servicio corra en otro puerto? ¿No has podido liberar ese puerto ni hacer que el servicio corra en otro puerto? ¿Qué comandos usaste para lograrlo? ¿Qué problemas o errores tuviste? etc.